# Closing Pygame which was run from a QThread stop responding

Tags: python, pygame, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I am running a pygame snake game from a game library made with PyQt5. I am running the with QThread. It works perfectly until I close the game. Whenever I close the game with the close button the pygame window and also the GUI stops responding. How do I solve this:

The game library GUI:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Snake(QtCore.QThread):
    def start_game(self):
        import Games.sanke_game #Imports and starts the game


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(853, 476)
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.singleContainer = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.singleContainer.setObjectName("singleContainer")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.singleContainer)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.snakeGame = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.singleContainer)
        self.snakeGame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.snakeGame.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
        self.snakeGame.setObjectName("snakeGame")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.snakeGame)
        self.guessGame = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.singleContainer)
        self.guessGame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.guessGame.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
        self.guessGame.setObjectName("guessGame")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.guessGame)
        self.targetGame = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.singleContainer)
        self.targetGame.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(55, 55))
        self.targetGame.setObjectName("targetGame")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.targetGame)
        self.spaceGame = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.singleContainer)
        self.spaceGame.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(55, 55))
        self.spaceGame.setObjectName("spaceGame")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.spaceGame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.singleContainer, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.multiContainer = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.multiContainer.setObjectName("multiContainer")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.multiContainer)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.multiContainer)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.computerContainer = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.computerContainer.setObjectName("computerContainer")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.computerContainer)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.ticTacToeGame = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.computerContainer)
        self.ticTacToeGame.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(55, 55))
        self.ticTacToeGame.setObjectName("ticTacToeGame")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.ticTacToeGame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.computerContainer, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


        # Button clicking function
        self.snakeGame.clicked.connect(lambda: self.game_choose("snake"))
        self.targetGame.clicked.connect(lambda: self.game_choose("target"))
        self.guessGame.clicked.connect(lambda: self.game_choose("guess"))
        self.spaceGame.clicked.connect(lambda: self.game_choose("space"))
        self.ticTacToeGame.clicked.connect(lambda: self.game_choose("tic-tac-toe"))


    # Functions for starting the game (Only choose the snake as its the only game now)
    def game_choose(self, choice):
        if choice == "snake":
            self.snake_worker = Snake()
            self.snake_worker.start_game()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Games"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Single Player"))
        self.snakeGame.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Snake"))
        self.guessGame.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Guess"))
        self.targetGame.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Target"))
        self.spaceGame.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Space Invader"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Multiplayer"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "VS Computer"))
        self.ticTacToeGame.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tic-Tac-Toe"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The snake game pygame file (The apple of snake in this game requires an image. So put any 32x32 image to avoid error):

```
import pygame
import random


# initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)


# Screen set & title
screen_width = 900
screen_height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")


# Object images
appleImg = pygame.image.load("Game_resources\\Snake\\apple.png")    # Put somg random images to avoid error

"""Variables"""

fps = 60


# Snake
snakeX = 32
snakeY = 32
snake_size = 32
snakeX_velocity = 0
snakeY_velocity = 0
velocityX = False
velocityY = False


# Apple
appleX = random.randint(20, 848)
appleY = random.randint(20, 548)


# Score text
score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)


#Game Over
over_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)
game_over_var = False

# Snakes and lenth
snk_list = []
snk_lenth = 1

"""Functions"""


def game_over():
    GameOver = over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, red)
    screen.blit(GameOver, (screen_width/3, screen_height/2.5))

def score_show():
    score = font.render("Score: " + str(score_value), True, black)
    screen.blit(score, (5, 5))

def apple_location(x, y):
    screen.blit(appleImg, (x, y))

def plot_snake(window, color, snk_list, snake_size):
    for x, y in snk_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, color, [x, y, snake_size, snake_size])



# Game running variable
running = True


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Loop
def gameloop():
    global running
    global screen
    global snakeX_velocity
    global snakeY_velocity
    global velocityX
    global velocityY
    global snakeX
    global snakeY
    global appleX
    global appleY
    global score_value
    global snk_lenth
    global snk_list
    global game_over_var


    while running:
        screen.fill(white)
        if game_over_var == True:
            screen.fill(white)
            game_over()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
            
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        game_over_var = False
                        snakeX_velocity = 0
                        snakeY_velocity = 0
                        velocityX = False
                        velocityY = False
                        snakeX = 32
                        snakeY = 32
                        snk_list = []
                        snk_lenth = 1
                        score_value = 0
                        gameloop()
        
        else:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        if velocityX == False:
                            snakeX_velocity = 4
                            snakeY_velocity = 0
                            velocityX = True
                            velocityY = False
                    
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        if velocityX == False:
                            snakeX_velocity = -4
                            snakeY_velocity = 0
                            velocityX = True
                            velocityY = False
                    
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        if velocityY == False:
                            snakeX_velocity = 0
                            snakeY_velocity = -4
                            velocityX = False
                            velocityY = True

                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        if velocityY == False:
                            snakeX_velocity = 0
                            snakeY_velocity = 4
                            velocityX = False
                            velocityY = True
                
            
            snakeX += snakeX_velocity
            snakeY += snakeY_velocity

            if abs(snakeX - appleX)<25 and abs(snakeY - appleY)<25:
                score_value += 10
                appleX = random.randint(20, 848)
                appleY = random.randint(20, 548)
                snk_lenth+=10



            head = []
            head.append(snakeX)
            head.append(snakeY)
            snk_list.append(head)

            if len(snk_list)>snk_lenth:
                del snk_list[0]

            if snakeX >= 848 or snakeX <=20 or snakeY >=548 or snakeY <=20:
                game_over_var = True

            score_show()
            apple_location(appleX, appleY)
            plot_snake(screen, black, snk_list, snake_size)
        clock.tick(fps)
        pygame.display.update()

gameloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not mix frameworks. The frameworks may interact poorly with each other or conflict completely. If it works on your (operating) system, that doesn't mean it will work on another (operating) system or with a different version of one of the frameworks. Mixing frameworks always means some kind of undefined behavior.
If you use Qt, then I suggest to develop the game with Qt as well (see [Qt Based Games](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Based_Games)).